Set multiple cells in DataFrame based on Series
I have a Pandas DataFrame which looks is constructed as follows:
=pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 1], [4, 6, 2]],
    columns=["A", "B", "C"],
    index=["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"],
)
     A  B  C
Foo  1  2  4
Bar  1  3  1
Baz  4  6  2

and a Series points to two of the cells by label:
=pd.Series(data=["Baz", "Foo"], index=["A", "C"])
A    Baz
C    Foo
dtype: object

I would like to multiply the values of the cells by -1, so that my resulting DF looks like:
     A  B  C
Foo  1  2 -4
Bar  1  3  1
Baz -4  6  2

I know I can do this iteratively:
for col, index in series:
    df.loc[[index], [col]] = df.loc[[index], [col]] * -1

But is there a one liner for setting multiple cells at once in this fashion?

This would be straightforward with numpy indexing, so let's use numpy with help from Index.get_indexer:
# convert the indices to positions
idx = df.index.get_indexer(series)
col = df.columns.get_indexer(series.index)

# modify the underlying numpy array in place
df.values[idx,col] *= -1

print(df)

Modified df:
     A  B  C
Foo  1  2 -4
Bar  1  3  1
Baz -4  6  2

I'm assuming here that all indices in the series are valid, if not this would create a -1 position in the indexer(s). In this case you have to decide what to do, the easiest might be to pre-filter the series to remove the non-existent indices.

NB. If you really want a one-liner you can use df.values[df.index.get_indexer(series), df.columns.get_indexer(series.index)] *= -1

You can crosstab the index and values of the series, so you get a 1 where you need to multiply:
df = df.mul(1 - 2*pd.crosstab(s, s.index), fill_value=1)

Break down:
# mask is 1 where we need to multiply value by -1, 0 otherwise
mask = pd.crosstab(s, s.index)

# mask now is -1 where we need to multiply, 1 otherwise
mask = 1 - 2*mask

# multiply with `mul` aligns the dataframes before actual multiplication
# fill_value fill the missing coordinates, e.g. `(A,Bar)`, with 1 
df = df.mul(mask, fill_value=1)

Note this method generate several intermediate dataframes of same size as df. So if df is large and s is sparse, it may be actually slower than the naive loop.

Nice trick with crosstab ;)

A shorter variant using boolean indexing: df[pd.crosstab(s, s.index).astype(bool)] *= -1

Another possible solution, which uses stack to get a multi-index with both index and column names, multiplies the selected values by -1 and then unstacks. (s is the series mentioned in the question.)
d = df.stack()
idx = list(zip(s, s.index))
d[idx] *= -1
d.unstack()


Yet another possible solution, which is a much shorter version of the previous one:
df.update(df.stack()[zip(s, s.index)].mul(-1).unstack())


Output:
     A  B  C
Foo  1  2 -4
Bar  1  3  1
Baz -4  6  2

